# Problem when changing mysql data directory in centos 7

Tags: php, linux, centos7

I have changed mysql data directory but there is still old path reflected

I used following method

```
mkdir /data/mysql
rsync -av /var/lib/mysql/ /data/mysql
```

Edit `etc/my.cnf` with following lines

```
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/server.sock
```

But when im checking using

```
@@datadir
```

its showing old path

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@datadir;
+-----------------+
| @@datadir       |
+-----------------+
| /var/lib/mysql/ |
+-----------------+
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Did you restart the server after change in config file?